# Sending pro-active messages to Microsoft Teams using Graph API (not Bot Framework)

Tags: python, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams

Recently noticed that Microsoft Flow (Power Automate) has enabled sending cards to individual chats. This was not possible in 2020, so I was wondering if it is now possible to send adaptive cards to Teams chats/group chats using Graph API? I'm playing around with 'Requests' package in Python and am able to send messages to group chats, but having no luck with sending cards.

Thank you for your replies and advice!

Answer (score 0):

You can send a adaptive card using graph api

```
POST https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/teams/{id}/channels/{id}/messages
Content-type: application/json
{
    "subject": null,
    "body": {
        "contentType": "html",
        "content": "<attachment id=\"74d20c7f34aa4a7fb74e2b30004247c5\"></attachment>"
    },
    "attachments": [
        {
            "id": "74d20c7f34aa4a7fb74e2b30004247c5",
           "contentType": "application/vnd.microsoft.card.adaptive",
           "content": JSON.stringify(card.attachments[0].content)
        }
    ]
}
```

Please go through the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/chatmessage-post?view=graph-rest-beta&tabs=http#example-3-cards) for more details.

Comment: Hi Mamatha! thank you for the reply. Is there any resource that breaks down the syntax and schema that Microsoft Teams allows?
I'm practically swinging in the dark hoping to make a hit with the correct syntax. For example, I would like to display a table with data in the card, is that possible?

Comment: @JunZhi - Please go through this [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/adaptive-cards/templating/) it may help you.

Comment: @JunZhi Please let us know does that help clarify.

Comment: hi @Mamatha-MSFT, I have tried the examples and am able to send the sample cards out. But what I am having difficulty with is modifying the card into what I need and I keep getting errors, I'm assuming my card format is the problem. Is it possible to send html tables using Microsoft Teams messages?

Comment: Hi @JunZhi - Currently Markdown and XML (HTML) formatting tags supports Text-only messages don't support table formatting for Teams. There is a [UserVoice](https://microsoftteams.uservoice.com/forums/555103-public/suggestions/33199846-tables-in-messages) on this. You can upvote if this needs to be consider as a future request.

Comment: Hi @Mamatha-MSFT, thank you for your prompt replies! will be looking forward to this enchancement in the future. One more question, is there a best way to troubleshoot what is wrong with my card formatting/schema? Or will I have to look on the web or post there for help? hahah

Comment: @JunZhi - You can design adaptive card in [Adaptive Card designer](https://adaptivecards.io/designer/). Please go through this [document](https://adaptivecards.io/explorer/Column.html) for more information related to adaptive card designs.